# How to pass a parameter to middleware function in Express JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

```
// state edit route
app.get("/map/:symbol/edit", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  State.findOne({symbol: req.params.symbol}, function(err, state){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else
    {
      res.render("edit", {state: state});
    }
  });
});
```

In the above code snippet, **isLoggedIn** is the middleware function to check for authentication. Its definition is given below:

```
// middleware function
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect("/admin");
}
```

So, the question is, how to pass a parameter like a string, an integer or a path variable to the middleware function so that it can be used in the routing url ?

Comment: Pass it from where? Middleware will always run before your terminating function, and middleware run in the same sequence as the order you define them in app.get() etc.

Comment: I want like isLoggedIn(var) so that i can access the var in function(req, res, next, var){} @LarsHoldaas

Comment: Fair enough, but how do you image your are going to call isLoggedIn? You never call it yourself, instead express calls it and all other functions in your middleware/terminating function-chain with the same three arguments: req, res and next.

Comment: Now if your idea is that you're going to do different operations based on which app.get/app.post etc. is called, you can check the req.originalUrl in the middleware. Other than that, you never actually call the function from your code. Express does it for you when it gets a request.

Comment: I'd recommend giving an accurate description of the behavior you want and me or someone else will give you a good suggestion for how to implement that behavior. But what you're specifically asking for is not how express works.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same requirement and this approach works for me.

**Middleware file `validate.js`**

```
exports.grantAccess = function(action, resource){
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const permission = roles.can(req.user.role)[action](resource);
            // Do something
            next();
        }
        catch (error) {
            next(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Use of middleware in **route** file. `grantAccess('readAny', 'user')`

```
router.get("/",grantAccess('readAny', 'user'), async (req,res)=>{
    // Do something     
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Cheers!

Comment: This is referred to as configurable middleware: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow this approach, it might do the job for you

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req);
    this.req = req;
    // assign value like this
    this.req.body.custom_data = ['zz', 'aaa', ....];
    next();
});

app.get("/map/:symbol/edit", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
   State.findOne({symbol: req.params.symbol}, function(err, state){
      if(err){
         console.log(err);
      } else {
         res.render("edit", {state: state});
      }
   });
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
   console.log(req.body);
   if(req.isAuthenticated()){
      return next();
   }
   res.redirect("/admin");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'm using it, I take a little bit of Hardik Raval answer.

```
helpers.validateRole = (roles) => {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
            const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[0]
            if (token == null) return res.json({error:true, msg: "Unauthorized"})
            const user = jwt.decode(token)
            let isValid = false
            roles.map((r,i)=>{
                if (r === user.role){
                    isValid = true
                }
            })
            if (isValid){
                // User role is valid
                next();
            }else{
                // User role is not valid
                util.returnError("Unauthorized", res);
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            next(error)
        }
    }
}
```

And I called like this.

```
router.get(  "/requirements/list_of_requirements/:page/:rows",  isAuthenticated, validateRole([6]),  async (req, res) => {
//* All the logic
})
```

Comment: Storing the user role within the JWT is not a good idea I think